# Incrementing an int from an object after it's constructed in C++

Tags: c++, class, int

I have a game, each turn it creates a new Bunny object. Each bunny has an age and I want the age to be incremented each passing turn for every object in the game.
 I made a method for the class which increments the age, but it only seems to increment it once. 
How do I proceed?

```
class Bunny 
{
private:
    std::string sex, color, name;
    int age;

public:
    void agePlusOne(void);

    Bunny();
    ~Bunny();
};

void Bunny::agePlusOne()
{
    age += 1; // Or age++;
}

int main() 
{
    int the_time;

    clock_t startTime = clock();   //Start timer

    clock_t testTime;
    clock_t timePassed;
    double secondsPassed;

    std::vector<Bunny> bunnies;   //Bunny objects container

    while (true) 
    {
        testTime = clock();
        timePassed = startTime - testTime;
        secondsPassed = timePassed / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        the_time = (int)secondsPassed * -1;

        if (the_time % 2 == 0)   //This is what happens each turn
        {

            for (auto e : bunnies) 
            {
                e.agePlusOne();   //All bunnies age one year
            }

            bunnies.push_back(Bunny());   //Adds bunny object to vector
        }
    }

    //End of program
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why a pointer!? isn't `age++;` good enough?

Comment: that's what i did the first time. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: age+= 1 will do the trick. Also in c++ you don't need the void in the function declaration std::string get_name() const; is fine.

Comment: It does something in this overly simplistic case. So I assure you the problem is with code you *did not show* us. I guess something is shadowed.

Comment: It still only increments it once

Comment: I can post the whole code if you want

Comment: If it only increments once, then you're only calling it once.

Comment: @Octav please do (if it is not too big)

Comment: @Octav At least show where `agePlusOne()` is being called from, in context.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you're incrementing the ages of copies of your bunnies.

Comment: Ok, i posted the whole code. Take a look

Comment: @Octav We don't want/need the full code.  What we need is a [mcve]

Comment: You grab age (`int tempAge = e.get_age();`), increment the internal age (`e.agePlusOne();`), but then check against the old age (`if(tempAge == 2)`). All you are doing is manipulating copies.

Comment: In your `for` loop, you iterate through your vector using `auto` which makes a copy of each element. Use a reference to make sure that you are actually modifying the objects themselves (ie. `for(auto& e : bunnies) {...}`.

Comment: Also, you should (virtually) *NEVER* manually call the destructor on an object unless you know what the side-effects will be (as in the case of using a placement new to allocate your own memory pool).

Comment: @callyalater i made tempAge for it to check if it is 2 years old and then make it an adult. But it actually never gets to 2 years old. When i run the code it outputs the age for each bunny and it's incremented once, but only once. That is actually my real question, why does it increment only once?

Comment: @callyalater This is true. Destructors are a *language* construct, not a game logic construct. If you want to be able to kill your bunnies, you will have to create the procedure yourself (ex: add a `bool` in its fields and add a setter)

Comment: @callyalater Oh ok, didn't know that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry for the whole code thing. This is my first question on StackOverflow. I will ask my next question in a minimalist way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here looks to be that you are dealing with copies of your bunnies vector in the innermost `for` loop.  When you write:

```
for (auto e : bunnies)
{
    // More code here
}
```

`e` is just a copy of whatever element is in the vector at that location, not the original element itself.

If you want to modify the elements in the vector, access them by *reference* and call their mutators accordingly. For example:

```
for (auto & e : bunnies)
//        ^
// Note the ampersand above.
{
    int tempAge = e.get_age();
    e.agePlusOne(); // Now this will change the internal state
                    // of `age` for this bunny.
    // More code
}
```

This will modify the *actual* object instead of just a copy.